# Set the value of textbox in a zend form from a controller and display the form

Tags: php, zend-framework

I have a Zend form where there are lot of textboxes. I need to set the value of these textboxes from the respective controller and present the form while performing an action. How can I acheive the same?

Comment: if $textbox consists of name of textbox, and $data is value what you would set.

$form = new Form();
$form->getElement($textbox)->populate($data);

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to use like this one:

```
$form = new Zend_From();
$textfield = new Zend_Form_Element_Text('textfield');
$textfield->setValue('your value');
$form->addElement($textfield);

<?= $form ?>
```